# Magento Extension config.xml conflicts

Tags: configuration

I am new to magento and try to make magento extension, Issue is my extension config.xml file in etc directory is conflict with other extension.

**First extension config.xml file data**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Pfay_Test>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Pfay_Test>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
           <routers>
              <routeurfrontend>
                  <use>standard</use>
                  <args>
                     <module>Pfay_Test</module>
                     <frontName>test</frontName>
                  </args>
               </routeurfrontend>
           </routers>
           <layout>
               <updates>
                    <test>
                         <file>test.xml</file>
                     </test>
               </updates>
           </layout>
    </frontend>
      <global>
         <blocks>
             <test>
                  <class>Pfay_Test_Block</class>
             </test>
          </blocks>
          <models>
            <test>
                 <class>Pfay_Test_Model</class>
                 <resourceModel>test_mysql4</resourceModel>
             </test>
            <test_mysql4>
                 <class>Pfay_Test_Model_Mysql4</class>
                 <entities>
                     <test>
                       <table>pfay_test</table>
                     </test>
                  </entities>
            </test_mysql4>
           </models>
    <!-- allow the plugin to read and write -->
          <resources>
            <!-- connection to write -->
            <test_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </test_write>
            <!-- connection to read -->
           <test_read>
              <connection>
                 <use>core_read</use>
              </connection>
           </test_read>
        </resources>
        <!---->
    </global>
</config>
```

**Second extenshion config.xml file data**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Rsignal_Contact>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Rsignal_Contact>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Rsignal_Contact</module>
                 <frontName>contact</frontName>
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

while i try to make 2nd config.xml then first extension stop working. please help me and guide me how i solve this problem.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from here:

```
<frontend>
   <routers>
      <routeurfrontend> <!-- this is the problem tag -->
          <use>standard</use>
          <args>
             <module>Rsignal_Contact</module>
             <frontName>contact</frontName>
          </args>
       </routeurfrontend>
   </routers>
</frontend>
```

See the tag I indicated in the code. That should be unique. Change it to something else in one of the modules and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to rename the tag `routeurfrontend` to match your module name (e.g. `pfaytest` and `rsignalcontact`), to avoid conflicts and to ease debugging.

In your case, the second module specifying a router `routeurfrontend` overrides the first one's router.